# Нужна ли запятая перед прилагательным после определяемого слова?

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли ставить запятую после «жертву»:

«Исследователи указывают на обычай посвящения, принесения коней в жертву(,) характерный для ираноязычных народов Евразии».

Comment: Семантика предложения неясная. Вроде бы посвящение и принесение в жертву - это разные вещи. Как они здесь связаны - непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая после "жертву" нужна, за ней следует оборот с прилагательным. Он (оборот) приравнивается к причастному.

[Запятые при опреде­лительных оборотах](https://therules.ru/comma-6/)

> Запятыми выделяются:
>
> Причастия и прилагательные, имеющие при себе пояснительные слова и
>   стоящие после определяемого существительного.

Подробнее, об исключениях и частных случаях, см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/150-zap-19-31).

---

*Исследователи указывают на **обычай посвящения**, принесения коней в жертву, **характерный для ираноязычных народов Евразии**.*